# NotApplicable marker with display pattern

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

Ok, so I'm pretty new to Cocoa, especially Bindings, but here's what I'm trying to do. I've got a Core Data model consisting of two entities: `Category` and `Item`. `Category` has a to-many relationship to `Item` called `children`, and `Item` has a relationship to `Category` called `parent`. `Item` has two attributes that `Category` does not have:  `quantity` and `desiredQuantity`. What I'd like to do is display the tree in an NSOutlineView with two columns. One column is bound to the `name` of either the `Category` or the `Item`. I want to the second column to display something along the lines of

> 2 of 5

for the `Item` rows and nothing at all for the `Category` rows. When I use a display pattern, the `Category` rows end up showing

> of

I noticed that if I don't use a display pattern for the second column, and instead just bind its Value to either the `quantity` or the `desiredQuantity`, the `Category` rows show nothing; its only if I try to use the display pattern.

How can I make it display nothing for the `Category` rows and still use the display pattern? Or can I?

Edit:
I guess I didn't explain what the NotApplicable marker has to do with anything - `Category` does have properties for `quantity` and `desiredQuantity`, but they just return NSNotApplicableMarker.

Comment: Is that the binding of a table view column?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for a custom [NSFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000029i) or just a read-only NSString property called "paginationString" ...